# foundation topbar dropdown menu padding error

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation

[image]

So I am making a menu with a dropdown and there is something very weird happening with foundation. The link is coming with a padding-right of 21rem !important and I am pretty sure it is coming from foundation. I don't have 21rem or any importants in my menu css. Here's the exact line of code that it is generating. I have a file that compiles all the css so it is hard to pinpoint exactly the cause.

```
.top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a {
  padding-right: 21rem !important; }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Without seeing how you generate the CSS and some of your JS, its hard to say what the problem could be

Comment: Do you used the minified version of the Foundation css or do you import all the .scss files?

Comment: I'm using ruby on rails and the foundation gem, version 5.02. I think that it imports all of the scss files and assumes rails will minify it later.

Answer (score 0):

target `.profile-menu` in your css and override it with `padding-right: 0 !important` if that doesn't work add an `id` to that `a` tag and target that `id`

Comment: wsn't me who downvoted but generally using `!important` is bad practice...http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

Comment: yeah sure, but if you're using something where 1. you cant figure out where code is coming from and 2. is already generating the tag `!important`....i dont see how bad practice (which I am a big advocate for) comes into play here. Blaine wants a solution, there it is.

Comment: per the article, you can set an id, which was the second thing I said

Comment: i know, hence i didnt downvote. Just add what you commented with to the answer, just so other users dont get the wrong idea.

Comment: I may have to end up adding the important for now despite it not being  very optimal. I don't like adding important to my css. Nothing against your solution though.

Comment: add an `id` and use `padding-right:0` then, `id`s take precedent over `class`

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is a problem with implicit units.

Edit your `bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/_top-bar.scss` file from

```
padding-#{$opposite-direction}: $topbar-link-padding + 20 !important;
```

to

```
padding-#{$opposite-direction}: $topbar-link-padding + rem-calc(20) !important;
```

In Foundation `commit 94312727c2dc18016bef51527e9913975612822b` this is in line 517.